# How to hide get and post parameters from the URL?

Tags: php, html

I have created a script that posts a value for a certain variable.

HTML:

```
<form action="post" action="func.php">
       <input name="name"></input>
</form>
```

func.php:

```
<?php
  $name = $_GET['name'];
  echo $name;
?>
```

Output:

```
Divya Mamgai
```

But when I check the URL in the address bar I see this:

```
http://.....func.php?name=Divya%20Mamgai
```

How can I remove that `?name=Divya%20Mamgai` bit from the address bar?

Comment: `action="post" action="func.php"` should be `method="POST" ...`.

Comment: Note that POST forms don't provide a good response to the BACK button; use method="GET" to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set your form to method "post". This causes the form to transmit data to the server in the HTTP request body instead of using the URL.

```
<form action="func.php" method="post">
  <input name="name"></input>
</form>
```

And then use the `$_POST` [superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) in PHP:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  echo $name;
?>
```